# Is there a way to know who responsed a e-mail?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

I don't have much information about the RMM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [RMM](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_reply_mail_management.htm&type=5) for that. It let's you configure how you want to treat the responses to your email.
- You can send an auto-response .
- You can get them into a monitored mailbox and take it from there .
- You can set up keywords for automated opt-out

Comment: But, if i want to put them in a Data Extension by SQL. Is it possible?

Comment: No that’s not possible. I don’t think you can access RMM data